# How to Plot chart from two different webform Submission data And Wand to Display annotated point

Tags: charts, highcharts, drupal-7, drupal-views, webforms-view-engine

![ Chart is plotted on View of webform submission type ][10]

[enter link description here](http://dev.hqcoders.com/kpi/statewide-progress-towards-meeting-20-by-2020-goal#overlay-context=statewide-progress-towards-meeting-20-by-2020-goal)

Hi,

I'm using Charts, high-charts,  webform, view modules to displaying a chart in drupal 7.

I need some extra functionality in charting and I'm unable to implement it.

1. Want to display alternate year in X-axis ( 1998, 2000, 2002, 2004 ...)
2. Want to display a particular annotation like image for a point (as displayed in image)
3. Want to plot a series  from other webform submission data, i.e how can I draw a graph from two webform submission data in drupal.

Note- I tried to plot a series (Y axis data) from different webform submission but data is not relating with x-axis and series is displayed before x-axis

Is there any way to customize the charts module in drupal so that I can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have categories, you can set tickInterval as 2, or modify category array

2) You can use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image)

3) What your webform return?